# Show "this question has an active bounty and cannot be closed" earlier, when it applies

Tags: feature-request, bounties, vote-to-close

If a bounty is active on a question, that question [cannot be closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067). However, attempting to vote to close works just fine until the "Vote to close" button is pressed. Only then does the "this question has an active bounty and cannot be closed" message pop up.

There may be a technical reason for this, but there's no workflow reason for it. Please show the message as soon as the "close" link is clicked.

Comment: [I just cant do it....](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kGISj.png)

Comment: There is (nowadays) a workflow reason of sorts: if some users have voted to close the question before it was bountied, clicking the "close" link to open the popup lets you see which close reasons they picked. However, we could still support that use case by opening the popup, but e.g. replacing the submit button with a big red notice saying that the question cannot currently be closed.

Comment: What about hiding the "close" button altogether?

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.50, my [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script now contains [an implementation of this feature.](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/68cdb600b9a0e4901790585259216567ed548e33/SOUP.user.js#L1609)

The way I implemented it is by detecting the presence of the bounty notice on the page and, if it's there, disabling all the radio buttons in the close popup that don't open a submenu.  This should make the dialog obviously and visibly non-functional (and also impossible to submit, since you can't actually select a close reason), while still preserving the *other* functionality of the popup (i.e. checking to see which reasons earlier close voters have picked).

There's also a bit of extra code for handling the close-as-duplicate subdialog, allowing you to search for potential duplicates and to see which duplicates others have picked, but not to actually select and submit one.

Of course, there's also a conspicuous explanatory message:

> [image: Screenshot of disabled close dialog due to bounty]

<sup>(The freehand arrow in the screenshot is probably redundant.  To do: Localize the message into languages other than English.)</sup>

In some later version of SOUP, I may consider replacing the current implementation with one that leaves the radio buttons enabled but instead "super-disables" the submit button, since I did actually end up adding such a feature to SOUP for [another feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358862).  But for now, the current implementation seems to work fine.  (Any reports of unexpected side effects are, of course, welcome!)