# Why not remove the "close" link for questions with an active bounty?

Tags: feature-request, bounties, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show “this question has an active bounty and cannot be closed” earlier, when it applies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90713/show-this-question-has-an-active-bounty-and-cannot-be-closed-earlier-when-it)

I tried to vote for a question on SO to be closed. I clicked the link, selected my reason and up popped the following.

[image]

Fair enough, I had not noticed the bounty. I've read the questions about how to handle the situation itself. But why is the "close" link still active anyway?

I propose one of the two following solutions:

- Don't show the "close" option at all when a bounty is active. This (as @MadScientist [suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134765/161198)) could lead to more Meta question on the missing option.
- Alternatively we have the very message illustrated above pop up immediately when clicking the link. That is, without having to select an actual reason for closure before.

Comment: @Ben Yeah, bingo. That one I didn't find.

Comment: I keep almost clicking the big orange box to close it.

Comment: Just vote to close. There's no bounty yet. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would lead to the situation where endless meta questions are posted, asking why the close link is missing on certain questions. I strongly prefer having the link there, with a tooltip explaining why you can't close instead of silently removing the link (like it happens with the edit link).

There might be merit in having some visual indicator that it is an active link, though. But as the link is already grey, the most obvious solution wouldn't work here.

It should also not even let you choose a reason, but complain earlier.

Comment: Complaining earlier would also be entirely acceptable. Should I make it a feature request instead?