# Why is the "close" link now shown on bountied questions?

Tags: discussion, support, bounties, vote-to-close

Related: [How can we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14591/155556)
Related #2: [Allow users to vote to close bountied questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121448/155556)

I just noticed that I am now able to click on **vote to close** on a bountied question!

Has the system changed?

If so, then what are the new rules?

It still says that I can't vote due to the bounty, but I don't remember the `close` link being there before when a bounty existed.

Comment: Please link to the question you're seeing this on.

Comment: @PopularDemand one such example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11794554/561731

Comment: @jadarnel27 read the OP.

Comment: @aman Your title confuses people. It makes them believe you believe one can vote to close a bountied question. (And I don't remember _not_ having a "close" link on bountied questions.)

Comment: So the __real__ question is "Is the 'close' link on questions with active bounties new?"

Comment: @PopularDemand I guess...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *click* on close, but when you actually select a reason you get the "This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed" message.

There've been requests to change the UI related to this for [at least a year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90713/show-this-question-has-an-active-bounty-and-cannot-be-closed-earlier-when-it).  The best would probably be to leave the close link (so it's not mysteriously missing), but give the message immediately instead of after a reason's selected.

Comment: Yes... I know that -- **read the OP**.... The `close` button did not used to be there when a question was bountied....

Comment: The system should just hide the close link - save both the user the time and the server some (small) load.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA I'm not sure that's true.  I think I saw an old question recently requesting that it be hidden since closing isn't actually an option.

Comment: @nhahtdh: It's more instructive to provide a link and then tell the user why they can't use it, than it is for the link to be mysteriously missing without explanation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: What you said about mysteriously missing link makes sense, but I think it is better to display the orange box right away rather than displaying the close reason.

Comment: @RobertHarvey we _do_ do the mysteriously missing edit link for when a person can't edit atm. why not for the close link as well?

Comment: Everyone can suggest edits.  Is the link called something else like "improve" for suggested editors?

Comment: @RobertHarvey when there is an edit in the queue and you do not have edit privs yet, the edit link did not used to show.

Comment: @aman Which confused the heck out of people, and if I recall correctly, that has been changed and the link is now just greyed out or something. I think hovering gets you a popup telling you why you can't suggest an edit at the moment.

Comment: @DanielFischer [Indeed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91172/always-show-the-edit-button-on-questions/138944#138944).

Comment: @TimStone [indeed](http://youtu.be/XtPgr94VYA4)?